# group by time seconds in R

Tags: r, time, group-by

Does anyone know how to group by 'time' seconds? The time variable has 30 observations per second.

```
   structure(list(time = structure(c(1475049600, 1475049600.03333, 
1475049600.06667, 1475049600.1, 1475049600.13333, 1475049600.16667, 
1475049600.2, 1475049600.23333, 1475049600.26667, 1475049600.3, 
1475049600.33333, 1475049600.36667, 1475049600.4, 1475049600.43333, 
1475049600.46667, 1475049600.5, 1475049600.53333, 1475049600.56667, 
1475049600.6, 1475049600.63333, 1475049600.66667, 1475049600.7, 
1475049600.73333, 1475049600.76667, 1475049600.8, 1475049600.83333, 
1475049600.86667, 1475049600.9, 1475049600.93333, 1475049600.96667, 
1475049601, 1475049601.03333, 1475049601.06667, 1475049601.1, 
1475049601.13333, 1475049601.16667, 1475049601.2, 1475049601.23333, 
1475049601.26667, 1475049601.3), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
), tzone = "GMT"), X = c(-0.059, -0.023, -0.016, -0.016, -0.016, 
-0.012, -0.016, -0.012, -0.016, -0.012, -0.016, -0.016, -0.016, 
-0.02, -0.02, -0.027, -0.016, -0.02, -0.016, -0.016, -0.02, -0.023, 
-0.016, -0.02, -0.012, -0.016, -0.012, -0.016, -0.016, -0.02, 
-0.02, -0.02, -0.02, -0.008, -0.02, -0.016, -0.016, -0.012, -0.016, 
-0.016), Y = c(-0.777, -0.777, -0.777, -0.777, -0.777, -0.777, 
-0.777, -0.781, -0.773, -0.777, -0.777, -0.777, -0.777, -0.773, 
-0.777, -0.777, -0.777, -0.777, -0.773, -0.777, -0.777, -0.777, 
-0.77, -0.777, -0.777, -0.777, -0.781, -0.777, -0.777, -0.773, 
-0.777, -0.777, -0.777, -0.773, -0.777, -0.777, -0.777, -0.777, 
-0.777, -0.777), Z = c(0.688, 0.688, 0.691, 0.691, 0.688, 0.688, 
0.688, 0.691, 0.691, 0.695, 0.688, 0.691, 0.691, 0.695, 0.691, 
0.688, 0.688, 0.688, 0.691, 0.691, 0.691, 0.691, 0.695, 0.691, 
0.691, 0.688, 0.695, 0.688, 0.691, 0.691, 0.688, 0.688, 0.688, 
0.688, 0.688, 0.691, 0.691, 0.695, 0.695, 0.691)), subject_name = "1", time_zone = "02:00:00", missingness = structure(list(
    time = structure(c(1475747248, 1475747249, 1475747250, 1475747292, 
    1475747293, 1475747294), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "GMT"), 
    n_missing = c(30L, 30L, 1230L, 30L, 30L, 32490L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1475747248", 
"1475747249", "1475747250", "1475747292", "1475747293", "1475747294"
)), old_version = FALSE, firmware = "1.5.0", last_sample_time = structure(1475748377, tzone = "GMT", class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt")), serial_prefix = "TAS", sample_rate = 30L, acceleration_min = "-8.0", acceleration_max = "8.0", header = structure(list(
    `Serial Number` = "TAS1E44150325", `Device Type` = "Link", 
    Firmware = "1.5.0", `Battery Voltage` = "3,88", `Sample Rate` = 30, 
    `Start Date` = structure(1475049600, tzone = "GMT", class = c("POSIXct", 
    "POSIXt")), `Stop Date` = structure(1475859600, tzone = "GMT", class = c("POSIXct", 
    "POSIXt")), `Last Sample Time` = structure(1475748377, tzone = "GMT", class = c("POSIXct", 
    "POSIXt")), TimeZone = "02:00:00", `Download Date` = structure(1475748377, tzone = "GMT", class = c("POSIXct", 
    "POSIXt")), `Board Revision` = "5", `Unexpected Resets` = "0", 
    `Acceleration Scale` = 256L, `Acceleration Min` = "-8.0", 
    `Acceleration Max` = "8.0", Mass = "77,1107028999572", Age = "22", 
    Limb = "Waist", DateOfBirth = "628890912000000000", `Subject Name` = "1", 
    `Serial Prefix` = "TAS"), class = c("gt3x_info", "list")), start_time = structure(1475049600, tzone = "GMT", class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt")), stop_time = structure(1475859600, tzone = "GMT", class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt")), total_records = 20929470L, bad_samples = FALSE, n_head = 40, row.names = c(NA, 
20929470L), class = c("activity_df", "activity_df", "activity_df", 
"data.frame"))
```

Comment: Could you please share your data using `dput`?

Comment: https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/group_by.html

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple way is to use `second` function from `{lubridate}` package. Here is an example using simple data:

```
example <- structure(list(time = structure(c(1569632400, 1569632400, 1569632400, 
1569632401, 1569632401, 1569632401), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
), tzone = ""), X = c(0, 3, 3, 2, 2, 0), Y = c(1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 
0), Z = c(1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))

example
                 time X Y Z
1 2019-09-28 08:00:00 0 1 1
2 2019-09-28 08:00:00 3 2 1
3 2019-09-28 08:00:00 3 1 1
4 2019-09-28 08:00:01 2 1 0
5 2019-09-28 08:00:01 2 1 0
6 2019-09-28 08:00:01 0 0 1

library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)

example |> group_by(second(time)) |> summarise(mean(X), mean(Y), mean(Z))

# A tibble: 2 × 4
  `second(time)` `mean(X)` `mean(Y)` `mean(Z)`
           <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>
1              0      2        1.33      1    
2              1      1.33     0.667     0.333
```